# How to remove a document in Mongoose, only if one of its fields matches some condition?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to delete one item only if it matches some condition. It would be something like this:

```
Session.findOne({ id:req.body.sessionId },function(err,session){
    if(session.user == req.body.userId) {
        session.remove();
    }
});
```

Which obviously doesn't work. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test multiple conditions at the same time in Mongoose. This should work for you.

```
Session.findOne({ 
  id: req.body.sessionId,
  user: req.body.userId
})
.remove()
.exec();
```

Answer (score 2):

Honestly, just do :

```
Session.remove({ "_id": req.body.sessionId },function(err,result) {

});
```

That's more efficient and safe.

The reason it's failing in your example is because the variable is not a string anymore but an ObjectId in the returned document. But it's not really safe so don't do it that way.

---

If you are being paranoid about the matching session then do it first:

```
if (session.user.toString() == req.body.userId) {
    Session.remove({ "_id": req.body.sessionId },function(err,result) {

    });
} else {
   // Not the same
}
```

And be aware that an ObjectId is not the same as a string in the request. Convert or cast one of them.

Comment: how do I test the if statement without removing the instance at once?

Comment: @bmpasini You don't need to. It either matches something ( _id is unique so one thing ) or nothing. The number affected will be returned in the result. See better handling for validating against the current user as added.

Comment: I ended up just using `Session.remove` inside the callback. I didn't need  to convert to string though...

Comment: @bmpasini What I was trying to teach you here is that if you do `.findOne()` and then `.remove()` you are hitting the database twice. Also there is no need to check that the `_id` value returned from `.findOne()` is the same as the one you asked for. If you want to check against an existing variable before removing then wrap the logic to check before hitting the database at all. That's how you do things efficiently.

Comment: how am I supposed to check `session.user` before querying Session?

Comment: @bmpasini There is no point checking the returned value from `.findOne()` is what you have asked for because it returns something or nothing, the same is true of just issuing `.remove()` in the first place, removes something or nothing. The "checking" example I refer to is where you actually already have something in the current request data of your framework that does not require an explicit database call ( though it may be doing it behind the scenes. Requesting an object from the database and then asking to remove it is not an efficient process. Just remove it.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not just combine the query?

```
Session.findOne({ id:req.body.sessionId, user: req.body.userId}).remove( callback );
```

Comment: how do I test the if statement without removing the instance at once?

Comment: You can test the statement by just doing a findOne without the remove.